# having trouble with ubuntu installing on galaxy s3 d2vzw

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Where/what would be the best way to go about doing this? I have my old s3 from verizon wireless and wanna play with ubuntu on it a bit to see if its something id be interested in.

Anyone able to help or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting

The release of Ubuntu Touch only supports Galaxy Nexus devices.  If you want it on your s3 you'll have to port it yourself (a serious undertaking, or a build would be available), wait for someone else to do it, or wait for Canonical's official build.